# Como alinhar um botão sempre para baixo?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, jsfiddle

Estou utilizando bootstrap da versão [4.0.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Peguei um exemplo aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/

Como eu posso fazer um botão sempre alinhado para **baixo** ?

Pode ver no jsfiddle, que o botão do card "pro" está pra cima, quero deixar ela sempre no bottom para igualar o card "free".

Aqui está o jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/34shLh1m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não creio que o Bootstrap possua classes próprias pra isso, portanto você pode alterar as classes no seu CSS para ajustar o elemento sempre no *bottom*.

Para isso criei uma classe `.embaixo` para o botão e ajustei a classe `.card` conforme abaixo:

```
.embaixo{
   position: absolute;
   left: 5%;
   bottom: 20px;
   width: 90%;
}

.card{
   padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

O posicionamento absoluto é para que o botão fique sempre no *bottom*, e o `padding` no `.card` é para compensar a diferença porque o posicionamento absoluto não influi na fluidez e pode ficar por cima do texto.

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34shLh1m/9/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer utilizando o *flexbox*, apenas sendo necessário que englobe as informações (`card-title` e `ul`) em uma outra `div`. Criei e dei o nome de `.card-info`. Ao `card-body` adicionei as classes `d-flex align-content-between flex-wrap`.

Exemplo no JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s2w2mkL/

Documentação do Bootstrap Flex (onde poderá encontrar diversas outras utilidades de grid/alinhamento): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/